# Nuxt models and use don't work on my machine

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So I tried to use composables and noticed they don't work. After I send the project to a friend it worked fine for him.
Yesterday I had a problem importing a module and wasn't able to use its functions.
Again for other people or on code sandboxes it worked fine.
I have all the requirements installed and don't get whats wrong.

It's a almost new windows installation so I don't think something is manipulating it.

Running nuxt v3.1.2 with node 18.14.1

I tried removing some vs code extensions because I thought that thay might be the problem but I havent noticed a difference.

Comment: Maybe try to remove `node_modules` and lock file and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.